# Cors security with cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I need send cookies between users and my server (node.js), for using http requests from browser i need set header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to value **'*'** (allow for all), and for use cookie i need sending request from user with query parameter: **withCredentials: true** and send response with header **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** as **true**, but for use this header i need set exact **protocol + domain + port** in header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**. Buy, how i can use exact domain and port if this app directed for all people.

What i need do for normal work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the `Origin` request header (added automatically by browsers) and echo it's value back as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value.

You do need to be *very* careful to make sure that you aren't using cookies in a way that would let a malicious third-party site cause problems for you or your users when your users visit their website (which has permission from CORS to access your site with credentials).

Comment: OK, but how then to get a session key for definition? Do not constantly throw it as a separate parameter

Comment: @kitsoRik — You've missed the point. You need to be very careful about letting bad websites do bad things with authorised users accounts. It doesn't matter what mechanism you use to handle the users' credentials.

Comment: And "be careful" is not the same as "never do this"

Answer (score 2):

First off, the CORS specification explicitly made the decision to restrict the combination of a server allowing all origins and credentials in the same request. If you configure your server in this way, you open your customers up to potential CSRF attacks, meaning malicious websites could use your customers' / users' cookies to hit your API and steal their data. Not a good situation. Ask yourself why you need the cookie to complete the request, and if there isn't a better solution such as routing all the requests through a specific front end.

To configure this, you can use the npm package cors, and set `corsOptions = { origin: true }`, as per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). This will use the requests 'Origin' header as the allowed Origin in the response.

Again, this is a terrible idea, but if you can justify it, and know why you are doing it, it is your API.

Comment: OK, but how then to get a session key for definition? Do not constantly throw it as a separate parameter